# Function to create a table from an already uploaded table

Tags: r

I've been searching for a way to take 2 columns from a table that I uploaded from excel to R and basically make another table with the same number of rows.
The original table has 222 rows (each row represents a participant) and of this table I want to take two columns to make this new table that will have the same amount of rows so I can then omit the NA values in these two columns. I've tried this code, but I get this result.

```
ep_public1=table(SCRAM$ep_public,SCRAM$bl_sex)
      1  2
  0   2 12
  1  23 60
  2  13 19
  3  20 31
  4  23 17
  NA  0  2
```

The ep_public variable ranges from 0 to 4, and has a NA response (after I create the new table I wish to omit or eliminate the 2 participants that did not respond). The bl_sex is just 1 or 2. Is there a way for me to do this?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: In order to give a [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it's helpful to provide some of your data, which you can do using `dput(head())`. Then, edit your question and include the `dput` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` function should by default drop `NA` values. I think you might have character `"NA"` values. (What is `class(SCRAM$ep_public)` ?) Try replacing them with real `NA` and then use `table`.

```
SCRAM[SCRAM == 'NA'] <- NA
ep_public1 = table(SCRAM$ep_public,SCRAM$bl_sex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data structure, you can potentially do something like this

```
ep_public1 <- SCRAM[ , c("ep_public", "bl_sex") ]
```